# PFFacebookUtil Timeout Error

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am having similar issue as mentioned here: https://www.parse.com/questions/error-when-trying-to-reauthorise-facebook-user

When my app starts up, if the user is already logged in it tries to fetch the user's profile image from Facebook:

```
- (void)getFacebookIdAndProfileImageWithSuccess:(void(^)(NSDictionary *))success {
    // Send request to Facebook to retrieve profile information
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
            return;

        // Result is a dictionary of user information
        NSMutableDictionary *userData = (NSMutableDictionary *)result;

        NSString *facebookId = userData[@"id"];
        [userData setObject:facebookId forKey:@"facebookId"];

        // Retrieve the user profile image
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/picture?height=55&width=55", BaseApiUrl, facebookId]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
        [userData setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
        [userData setObject:[imageUrl absoluteString] forKey:@"imageUrl"];

        success([NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:userData]);
    }];
}
```

Well it takes a long time for the request to return and when it does it reports an error:

```
"Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x146aa790 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x146a1710 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1455c110 "The request timed out."}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<PFReceptionist: 0x14685310>}"
```

Comment: I tried to open https://graph.facebook.com/ in my browser and it did not. Could that be the problem? Facebook API is down?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my app and installed it again. This resolved the issue. The problem might have been that before I started getting this error I was trying to resolve another Facebook related issue my app was having. And one of the things I tried was deleting my Facebook account Settings > Facebook. Maybe that had something to do with this error, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState status,NSError *error){
        if(error)
        {
            [self hideLoadingMode];
            NSLog(@"Facebook Error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
// end you can use every thing you want
        }
        else{
            if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
                [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
NSlog(@"user ID %@",[user objectForKey:@"id"]);
}else{
                        [self hideLoadingMode];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
```

i hope this help you

Comment: you have to import: #import "FBSession.h"

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right in using the graph api directly rather than using the Parse utilities. I am losing trust in Parse. But before I could try your solution, I simply deleted my app and installed it again and the problem went away. Who knows why :(